# Clarification on polynomial used in Rijndael MixColumns implementation

Tags: aes, rijndael

I'm seeing the fundamental function in open source code for Rijndael MixColumns implementation. (Picture below)
If i translate the 8'h1b correctly, it is represent the polynomial of $x^4+x^3+x+1$.

However looking at the wikipedia explanation, the multiplied modulo is $x^4+1$.
May i know how to link them together? Anything I interpret wrongly?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph [Rijndael MixColumns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns). I'm pretty sure that there are dupes for your question.

Comment: @kelalaka, Thanks for guidance. So it is due to the shift operation, so the IP from x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1 become x^4+x^3+x+1 ? But i still don't understand how the multiplied module x^4+1 come into the picture?

Comment: `8'b1` is the [AES(Rijndael)'s s Galois field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael's_(AES)_finite_field).  $ x^4+1$ is used when each column is multiplied with fixed $a(x)$. There is a nice tutorial [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)